# remove duplicate 2D numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to remove some "duplicate" items in below array:

```
arr = array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

In the above array, `arr[:, 0]`, `arr[:, 3]` and `arr[:, 4]` should be seen as duplicates. And finally, I want this result:

```
arr = array([[1, 2, 3],
             [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Could you add some more info? How large is your real problem? What type and range are the entries? Are columns like (1, 1, 0) and (0, 1, 0) possible and would they be considered equal?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sorry about that. The array is very large, like 2*10000. And there are many arrays like this. Every column, like [1,2,3], equals its permutations(like [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,2,1], [3,1,2]).

Comment: It would be best to update the question as not everybody reads comments. Also, for finding the best solution almost any piece of info is useful: Not only the total size but the actual shape nrows x ncols (Or do you mean 2 x 10000?). Again, can a column have repeat values and if yes, how should those be treated? And finally, what dtype is the data? Because if as in your example they are small ints optimizations are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Pandas, you can use [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to create a Boolean indexer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

arr_dups = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(arr.T)).duplicated().values
res = arr[:, ~arr_dups]

print(res)

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not familiar with pandas. Can I just use numpy to accomplish this?

Comment: @fanronghong, Possibly, but *probably* not as simply in terms of syntax. Do keep the question open to see if better solutions emerge.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
arr_sorted = arr.copy() # copy the array so your input is not sorted
arr_sorted.sort(0) # sort row such as duplicates are in the same order
_, indices = np.unique(arr_sorted, axis=1, return_index=True) # find unique indices
arr_unique = arr[:,indices] # select indices
print(arr_unique)

# [[1 2 3]
#  [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Just to shorten your code, you could do directly: `arr[:,np.unique(np.sort(arr,axis=0), axis=1, return_index=True)[1]]`